# Supporting adding/deleting of a java object in JNI C++

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a pattern in my JNI code of `addObject(object)` and `removeObject(object)` where I'm I need to add something to a C/C++ map and remove it using those methods.

I've [read the android article on JNI memory management](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#local_and_global_references) and it says you shouldn't expect calls to JNI to return the same `jobject` reference to a JNI method for the same object.

My JNI looks like this so far for the add/remove:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_nicholas_MyClass_addObject(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject thisObject, jobject objectToAdd) {
    jobject newJavaObject = jenv->NewGlobalRef(objectToAdd);
    stdMap[newJavaObject] = //Some C++ Object;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_nicholas_MyClass_removeObject(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject thisObject, jobject objectToRemove) {
    jobject newJavaObject = jenv->NewGlobalRef(objectToAdd);
    stdMap[newJavaObject] = NULL;
}
```

What is the best way to perform this action? Or is it simply this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_nicholas_MyClass_addObject(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject thisObject, jobject objectToAdd) {
    deviceListenerMap[objectToAdd] = //Some C++ Object;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_nicholas_MyClass_removeObject(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject thisObject, jobject objectToRemove) {
    deviceListenerMap[objectToRemove] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what the type of deviceListenerMap is, but if possible, I would use the hashCode() returned by the Java object to store it in the map.  Make sure you **copy** all your values to the "Some C++ Object" and that the objectToAdd has the correct [hashCode and equals method overrides](http://javapapers.com/core-java/hashcode-and-equals-methods-override/) that suit your needs.

> JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_nicholas_MyClass_addObject(JNIEnv*jenv, jobject thisObject, jobject objectToAdd) {
>
> jclass classToAdd = GetObjectClass(jenv jobject objectToAdd);
>
> jmethodID id = GetMethodID(env, classToAdd, "hashCode", "(V)I");
>
> jint val = CallIntMethod(env, objectToAdd, id);
>
> deviceListenerMap[val] = //Some C++ Object;
>
> }

Comment: That's a really solid idea. Thank you.